# react: Initial state value is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set an initial value to my states. I used `constructor` to populate some values to my state.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export default class RandomWords extends Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const str="Italy quake: Norcia tremor destroys ancient buildings";
    const words = str.split(" ");
    this.state= {
      activeWord:0,
      activeLetter:0,
      words:words
    };
  }
      render(){
        console.log("words are:"+this.props.words);
          return(<div>
              {  this.props.words }
            </div>)
      }
}
```

and then i used `mapStateToProps` to connect `state` to `props`. Here is the container:

```
import RandomWords from '../components/RandomWords';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

function mapStateToProps(state){

    return ({words:state.words,
            activeLetter:state.activeLetter,
            activeWord:state.activeWord});
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RandomWords);
```

As you see, in my `render()` function, I have `console.log("words are:"+this.props.Words);` and i expect to see the splitted words.
But in console there is only `undefined`

Comment: redux state != component state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is used to map the [Redux state](http://redux.js.org/docs/Glossary.html#state) from your store to the component's props.

However, you are initializing the [component state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class). Two different concepts. You can **access the component state via `this.state`**:

```
 render(){
     console.log("words are:" + this.state.words);
     return(<div>
         {this.state.words}
     </div>)
  }
```

Comment: so how can i initialize the redux state?

Comment: @Salman Have a look at the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/). They offer a great explanation on how to integrate Redux with your app.